# How to replace xml attribute value?

Tags: xml, ant

I'm looking for a way to update an xml file attribute value. For example the following xml I would like to replace the attribute `android:versionCode` value `30003` with another value. I'm having a hard time understanding how ant can do that using replace or regex.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.app.see"
    android:installLocation="auto"
    android:versionCode="30003"
    android:versionName="@string/app_version" >
</manifest>
```

Answer (score 4):

If it is really that simple, you could use **[replaceregexp](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/replaceregexp.html)**:

```
<property name="newVersionCode" value="30004"/>
<replaceregexp file="${src}/AndroidManifest.xml"
               match='(android:versionCode=").*(")'
               replace="\1${newVersionCode}\2"
               byline="true"
/>
```

Otherwise, you should consider using the **[XSLT task](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/style.html)**. You would want to copy the original file into a temp directory, then apply a stylesheet where the new value is specified as a parameter, and generate the output over the original manifest.

Comment: Its deleting the next attributes(ex versionName), if the entire xml tag is in the single line. Do we have any other way to resolve it?

Comment: Either tighten up the regex, or look to use a more robust find and replace implementation, such as the XSLT task.